# Py2Exe can't find module

Tags: python, py2exe, winpcap

I've trying to "compile" script including package "pcapy", that I manually compiled with

```
python setup.py install
```

but py2exe can't find him. I've tried to add option in setup.py

```
options={
        "py2exe":{
                "packages": ["pcapy"]
        }
}
```

But it's not helped. Error that I've got(same if change "include" to "packages")

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    "includes": ["pcapy"]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
```

ImportError: No module named pcapy

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include 'pcapy' ?

```
options = {
    "py2exe": {
        "includes": ["pcapy"],
        "excludes": [...],
        "packages": [...],
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, same result.

Comment: I've added it to question.

Comment: I solve my problem - pcapy package was in .egg, so I run python setup.py install_lib in it's folder(so it's copy .pyc file to site-packages) and now it's works